# Jailbreak iPod touch 4G (6.1.3)

Tags: ipod

Does anyone know how to jailbreak an iPod touch 6.1.3 under ubuntu (12.04 LTS)? Better if you have a terminal sudo way!

[Already tried evasi0n but it seems that the 6.1.3 is too advanced to be supported]

Thank you in avance!

Comment: Do you mean, how to jailbreak it through a USB connection to a computer running Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [evasi0n jailbreak page](http://www.evad3rs.net/2013/05/jailbreak-613-iphone-4s-iphone-5-ipod.html), it is not possible to use evasi0n to jailbreak post-iOS 6.1.2 devices with the evasi0n jailbreak. There are lots of gimmicks out there that claim you can, but for now the only way to jailbreak that device is [with redsn0w](http://www.evad3rs.net/2013/03/ios-613-jailbreak-ipod-touch-4g.html), which is only available for OS X and Windows.